# How can the @DocumentId annotation be used fields for Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently integrating Firestore documents within a Kotlin application using an annotated POJO to pull the data in. As part of this I also need the ID of the document.

I'm trying to do this using the new @DocumentId notation described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html)...

However the annotation isn't being recognised in my POJO class (unresolved reference: DocumentId)

In my gradle file I have...

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
```

In my model class I have...

```
data class DocumentModel(
    @DocumentId var id: String
    @PropertyName var field1: String
    ...etc...
)
```

The other annotations work fine, it's just the DocumentId one which isn't working. Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: Tried to however it says 'unresolved reference' when I use `import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentId`

Comment: I'm not having a problem.  Make sure you've synchronized gradle with your project.

Comment: Syncronized but no change. Invalidated caches, restarted, sync'd and working fine now. Thanks @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1):

According to official document (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html),

> This annotation is applied to a property that is not writable (for example, a Java Bean getter without a backing field).

So, you have to use `val` instead of `var`.

```
data class DocumentModel(
    @DocumentId val id: String
    ...etc...
)
```